# Fancy Box Styling/ Conflict Centering

Tags: position, styling

My product image gallery uses a fancy box script and since i installed a plugin, i am having a small problem with the images popping up, then immediately jumping to the upper left corner.

i have tried adding stying to recenter it but its not working.

here is a product page:
http://a1decals.com/products-page/tribal-symbols-decals/flags-decals/america-american-flag-decal-sticker/

if you click on an image in the gallery you can see it popup.

i inspect the image element with firebug and get:

```
<div id="fancybox-wrap" style="width: 695px; height: auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; opacity: 1; transition: all 0s ease; -webkit-transition: all 0s ease;">
```

and i tried adding:

```
.fancybox-wrap { 
top: 50% !important; 
left: 50% !important; 
}
```

and

```
#fancybox-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50% !important; 
  left: 50% !important;
}
```

i cant seem to override whatever is restyling that popup. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which version of fancybox are you using?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce-dynamic-gallery/  is the plugin. i dont know where to look at what version of fancy box it uses